# WireGuard VPN Causing Connectivity Issues with Hyper-V, Windows Sandbox, WSL, and WSA

Tags: networking, dns, hyper-v, wireguard, windows-sandbox

I'm facing an issue with WireGuard VPN on my Windows 11 Pro 22H2 system. The problem arises when I use WireGuard VPN, which disrupts the connectivity of services like Hyper-V, Windows Sandbox, WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), and WSA (Windows Subsystem for Android).

Interestingly, while using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), I've discovered that I can ping IP addresses successfully, but domain names fail to resolve. A workaround involves editing the `/etc/resolve.conf` file within WSL. However, I'm striving for a more comprehensive solution that addresses the broader connectivity issue across all these services.

**System configuration details:**

- Operating System: Windows 11 Pro 22H2
- VPN: WireGuard

How can I configure my Windows 11 Pro 22H2 system to ensure uninterrupted functionality of services like Hyper-V, Windows Sandbox, WSL, and WSA while maintaining a connection to a remote server through WireGuard VPN? I've experimented with modifying the `/etc/resolve.conf` file within WSL, but I'm seeking a more holistic solution that covers all these services.

If anyone has encountered and resolved a similar challenge or possesses expertise in networking and VPN configurations on Windows systems, I would greatly appreciate your help.